# PHP file_get_contents for dynamically generated urls/pdf

Tags: php, html, url, pdf, zip

I want to loop through an array of urls and create a single zip file. The urls are dynamically generated pdf files/invoices. The programme works fine for physically existing files but for  the dynamically generated ones, it gets the html source code/page not the pdf.

Is there an alternative to using : file_gets_contents ?.

Below is a simulation code:

```
// prepare array of URL's/files

$files = array(
     "1" => "http://localhost/app/addon/test.pdf", //works
     "2" => "http://localhost/app/addon/test2.pdf",//works
     "3" => "http://localhost/app/index.php?section=flight-fatturazione&option=getPdf&tipo=invoice&id=6", //doesn't work
     "4" => "http://localhost/app/index.php?section=flight-fatturazione&option=getPdf&tipo=invoice&id=4",
     "5"=>  "http://localhost/app/index.php?section=flight-fatturazione&option=getPdf&tipo=invoice&id=2"
);

// create new zip opbject
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// loop through url/file array
foreach($files as $file){
   // download file
   // this gets file contents, what to do when file is created on the fly
   $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
   // add it to the zip
   $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
}
   // close zip
$zip->close();

   // send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
```

Currently, the code creates a zip with the with 2 pdf file(i.e the file physically sitting server :test.pdf, test2.pdf) and 3 html files even though accesing the urls directly generate pdfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going around for a long time and trying different solutions, I solved the problem. As I mentioned in my question, I was generating invoices on the fly  and trying to get the contents using

```
file_get_contents
```

by passing the url of the generated invoice. This returned html pages in the zip instead of the pdf. There were suggestions to use curl and simulate an http request but this did not solve the problem. All this was to avoid code duplication in my application, but  in the end I had no option.

So for each invoice i call function that creates it dynamically and then i get the content with file_get_contents

```
function createInvoiceContent($invoice_id){

   require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

   // create new PDF document
   $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

   /* Do a bunch of stuff to create the invoice */



   // Close and output PDF document
   // This method has several options, check the source code documentation  for more information.
   $invoice_content = $pdf->Output('invoice_name.pdf', 'I');
   return $invoice_content;
}
```

The i can call this function when i need it.

```
   //get pdf invoice  file
    $invoice = file_get_contents(createInvoiceContent($invoice_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the files 3-5 as .php-files. Does renaming them to .pdf work?

If, as you say, you're receiving html files, do they contain the PHP-code to generate them? (As in, is it returning the code of index.php?) Curious to see if they're actually getting processed. If these both don't work, do you need specific cookies or other settings (session?) in order to make a request to get the pdf?

Comment: The urls, 3-5 when accessed,   open up pdf/invoice file( when user is logged in  obviously). My idea is to get the pdf and add it to zip and then download it.  When debugging, $download_file = file_get_contents($file); contains an html page not the pdf as expected.

Comment: "When user is logged in obviously".
If the user is not logged in, they're served a HTML-page? This would explain why file_get_contents() returns a HTML-page. It's requesting the page without any cookies or session set (= not logged in). You can either use curl to first login, get the cookies and then curl to download the page or go for the easy way, check $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] if the request was made from localhost and then allow it. Alternatively, make the PDF-creation in index.php in a different file which you use to create the file at runtime.